How do you subclass or otherwise conveniently compose the "initialization arguments" of a HStack?
Say we have
HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 12) {
  blah
  blah
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.background(.green)
.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 4, bottom: 0, trailing: 12))

How to compose that for use everywhere?
Can it be done?

You can encapsulate the modifiers into a single one.

cheers @MojtabaHosseini !  right, but that doesn't help with the actual "arguments to the HStack form" part!  in fact if you notice the original edit of the question, it shows exactly that and then asks exactly that, GMTA  :) I just today shortened the question as you can see, to make clearer the excellent answer.

You can write BlahStack like this:
public struct BlahStack<Content: View>: View {
    let alignment: VerticalAlignment
    let spacing: CGFloat
    let content: Content

    public init(
        alignment: VerticalAlignment = .top,
        spacing: CGFloat = 12,
        @ViewBuilder _ content: () -> Content
    ) {
        self.alignment = alignment
        self.spacing = spacing
        self.content = content()
    }

    public var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: alignment, spacing: spacing) {
            content
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.green)
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 4, bottom: 0, trailing: 12))
    }
}

